# Find critical points, regular value, regular points

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by:

$(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow f(x,y)= x^2 - y^2$.

Find critical points, regular value, regular points.

### My attempt:

$[D(a,b)f]=[2a -2b]$. This has rank $1$ since the number of non-zero rows is $1$, except at $(a,b)={\{\vec0\}}$. $a\in \mathbb{R}^2$ is a critical point of $D(a,b)f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ if it has rank less than $m$. Here, $n=2,m=1$. ${\{\vec0\}}$ has rank $0<m$, so ${\{\vec0\}}$ is a critical point of $f$.

A regular value of $f$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^m-C_f$, here $C_f$ denotes the critical points of $f$. So in this case, the regular value of $f$ (denoted by $R_f$) is $R_f=\mathbb{R}-{\{\vec0\}}$.

The set of regular points of $f$ is $f^{-1}(R_f)$ so .. it is $f^{-1}(0)$, which is a manifold since,by definition, the inverse image of a regular value is a manifold.

If my attempt is correct, is there a way to calculate $f^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: It looks okay to me, I think for $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, we just need the gradient to be $0$. As for $f^{-1}(0) = \{ x^2 - y^2 = 0 \} = \{ x^2 = y^2 \}$. So it looks like the preimage is some $X$ shape.